# Embedded servlet container does not handle META-INF/resources in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

My WAR application use non-Spring library (for JSF). The library initializes using `servletContext.getResource("page.html")`. `page.html` is within a JAR in WEB-INF/lib, packaged as `META-INF/resources/page.html`

That works excellent when I deploy WAR on servlet container. But when I run application as executable WAR it does not work because embedded servlet container does not scan classpath META-INF/resources.

For example for Undertow classpath resource manager is not used:

```
private ResourceManager getDocumentRootResourceManager() {
    File root = getCanonicalDocumentRoot();
    if (root.isDirectory()) {
        return new FileResourceManager(root, 0);
    }
    if (root.isFile()) {
        return new JarResourceManager(root);
    }
    return ResourceManager.EMPTY_RESOURCE_MANAGER;
}
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/undertow/UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java#L466

Time for question: why embedded servlet container ignores `META-INF/resources`? It is a problem to make executable Servlet 3.0 applications.

Similar issues:

[Embedded Tomcat, executable jar, ServletContext.getRealPath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849636/embedded-tomcat-executable-jar-servletcontext-getrealpath)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4218

Comment: I've used spring boot a lot and still hadn't heard of executable war before. I wonder how supported that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following configuration:

```
@Bean
public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory =
    new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(new UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo) {
            deploymentInfo.setResourceManager(
                new ClassPathResourceManager(deploymentInfo.getClassLoader(),
                     "META-INF/resources"));
    });
    return factory;
}
```

Generally, I think that it is underdocumented how embedded web container behaves. Spring Boot developers are happy if embdedded web container offers some subset of features to application, people who migrate existing application expects embedded container provides all features of regular container. For example ServletContainerInitializers are ignored in embedded: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/321